# Send GET parameter when a href is clicked

Tags: forms, jsp, parameters, get, submit

I have a JSP page called page1.jsp, and a second one called page2.jsp. page1.jsp has an href link as follows:

```
   <a id= "l1" href="page2.jsp">WhenPressedSendParam</a>
```

When the link above is clicked, I want to send a given GET parameter(let's say keyword=5) to page2.jsp. In other words, I want the link to open the url page2.jsp?keyword=5.

How can I do it with hyperlinks instead of forms with submit inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do it like this

```
  <a id= "l1" href="page2.jsp?keyword="${example.number}>WhenPressedSendParam</a>
```

where example is a class with a numeric variable called number

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped! one last thing: When I try to display the parameter in page2.jsp, I get a 404 error. I try to print it in page2.jsp like this :  <b>The parameter received is:</b>
       <p><%= request.getParameter("keyword")%></p>

Comment: try passing it like like this <a id= "l1"<a href="page2.jsp?keyword=<%=example.number%>">